# onServiceDisconnected() not called after calling Service stopSelf()

Tags: android, service

I have an `Activity` in which I start and bind to a download `Service`.

When calling `stopSelf()` in the `Service`, `onServiceDisconnected()` in the `Activity` is not called.

I would expect it to be called, since if the `Service` is stopped, all bound activities should be unbound.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to the official document, onServiceDisconnected() would be called if the service crashed or was killed. Link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html

> Called when a connection to the Service has been lost. This typically happens when the process hosting the service has crashed or been killed. This does not remove the ServiceConnection itself -- this binding to the service will remain active, and you will receive a call to onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder) when the Service is next running.

Comment: Ok. So I'll send a `Broadcast` to notify the `Service` has stopped.

Comment: If you bind to the service then you can just send a notice and then called stopSelf()

Comment: `stopSelf()` is called directly in the `Service` (when there is no more downloading to do), not by a method from the `Activity`.

Comment: Yes, but you can either send a Broadcast or send a message through a Messenger.

Comment: They should have named the method onServiceCrash instead.

Answer (score 37):

Simply sending a notification to a bound client and calling `stopSelf()` (or `stopService()`) won't actually accomplish what you are trying to do.  You have to call `unbindService()` in the bound client (and the service must have no other bound clients) in order to actually destroy the service.

There are two types of Services, "started" services and "bound" services.  They are not mutually exclusive.  If you started the service using `startService()`, you have a "started" service.  If you start the service through `bindService()`, it is bound.  If you bind to the service and also use `startService()`, it is both.  So there are three possible options for managing a service's lifecycle:

1) Started Service:
you call `startService()` to start it; service will only be stopped by calling `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`.

2) Bound Service:
you call `bindService()` and pass in the `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag.  Other clients can bind and unbind to the service at will, the service will be automatically destroyed when all clients have detached.  In this case, calling `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` has no effect.

3) Combo:
clients bind to the service and you have also called `startService()`.  In this case, calling `stopSelf()` or `stopService()` will only destroy the service once all clients have detached.  Likewise, the service won't be destroyed automatically when all clients have detached, until `stopSelf()` or `stopService()` have been called.

The documentation for the lifecycle for combo services says:

> These two paths are not entirely separate. That is, you can bind to a
>   service that was already started with `startService()`. For example, a
>   background music service could be started by calling `startService()`
>   with an Intent that identifies the music to play. Later, possibly when
>   the user wants to exercise some control over the player or get
>   information about the current song, an activity can bind to the
>   service by calling `bindService()`. ***In cases like this,
>   `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` does not actually stop the service
>   until all clients unbind.***

So in your case, you have a bound client.  Calling `stopSelf()` doesn't forcibly disconnect bound clients, so you have to explicitly notify your client that the service wants to shutdown, and then your client has to call `unbindService()` before the service is destroyed.  You can accomplish that in a variety of ways, most simply through a broadcast or an IBinder interface, or a messenger or AIDL if you are communicating with your service across processes.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. So when calling `stopSelf()` from my `Service`, I must also send a `Broadcast` to my client to tell him to unbind.

Comment: You wrote: "..the service will be automatically destroyed when all clients have detached. In this case, calling stopService() or stopSelf() has no effect." - This is not true. I have two apps. One app provides the service and the other app binds to using bindService. I can terminate the service inside the app that hosts the service using stopSelf and it will in fact destroy the service, even while the other app is bound to it. So the statement that it "has no effect." is wrong. The client app that is bound to this service will never get any notification that the service has been terminated.

Comment: @AndroidDev: My statement was based on the documentation - "in cases like this, stopService() or stopSelf() does not actually stop the service until all clients unbind." So in this case I would say the documentation is wrong, or it's a bug. I would speculate that the fact that stopSelf destroys the bound service probably has something to do with you accessing the service in App A from App B which is running in another process? (Unless you configured them to run in the same process?)

Comment: @AndroidDev: For info, the updated docs say: "A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Once neither of these situations hold, the service's onDestroy() method is called and the service is effectively terminated." (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#service-lifecycle). So it sounds like what you are describing is unexpected behavior and you should probably file a bug report